# Firebase Cloud Messaging not working on Android Studio emulator

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-emulator, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am doing this [tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/5e4b26e26cdeb308204b427f/flutter-tutorial-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-push-notification) on Djamware to make a Flutter app that is able to receive notification from FCM. I have strictly followed the guideline but still get an error message in the end. (*highlighted in the image below*)

[image]

For some reasons, the error does not stop the app from running on my emulator, but when I try to send a message from FCM console nothing happens at all. I am running the emulator under my company firewall and I have to set up a proxy for it to access the internet, so that might be the case here.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562897/firebase-notifications-not-working-in-android-emulator) on this site but the answer does not address my issue.

Also, it's worth noting that this app runs perfectly fine on my physical device.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the app on emulator and install it again ? The important part is to uninstall it, not install over the existing app.

Comment: I have reinstalled at least three times.

Comment: Does the emulator has Google Play Services installed?
source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-play

Comment: Yes, I've installed Google Play. But not sign in it yet.

Comment: Strange, can you export and provide your emulator profile?